# How to update a nested object, pushing new dictionary to an array?

Tags: python, pymongo

There's a document in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
    _id: 'd2f5',
    url: 'https://exam.pl/b-4',
    creation_time: '2023.07.07 16:28:45'
}
```

If a `check` appears for the first time, I'd like to have it updated like this:

```
{
    _id: 'd2f5',
    url: 'https://exam.pl/b-4',
    creation_time: '2023.07.07 16:28:45',
    checks: {
        '10.08.2023-11.08.2023': {
            start_date: '10.08.2023',
            current_temp_forecast: '29.5',
            temp_forecast_history: [
                {
                    '2023.07.07 18:08:21': '29.5'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When existing `check` gets updated with new value, I'd like to have the old value stored in `temp_forecast_history` together with the new value, and have the current value extracted one level up:

```
{
    _id: 'd2f5',
    url: 'https://exam.pl/b-4',
    creation_time: '2023.07.07 16:28:45',
    checks: {
        '10.08.2023-11.08.2023': {
            start_date: '10.08.2023',
            current_temp_forecast: '28.2',
            temp_forecast_history: [
                {
                    '2023.07.08 19:39:52': '28.2'
                },
                {
                    '2023.07.07 18:08:21': '29.5'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How to achieve it, using `pymongo`?

Already tried doing updates like:

```py
update_query = {
                "$set": {
                    f"checks.{check}.start_date": start_date,
                    f"checks.{check}.current_temp_forecast": current_temp_forecast,
                },
                "$addToSet": { # used "$push" before, but with error as well
                    f"checks.{check}.temp_forecast_history": {
                        "$each": [
                            {
                                timestamp: current_temp_forecast
                            }
                        ],
                        "$position": 0
                    }
                }
            }

collection.update_one({"_id": document_id}, update_query)
```

But it failed with error saying:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not allowed in the context of an update's replacement document. Consider using an aggregation pipeline with $replaceWith., full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 52, 'errmsg': "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not allowed in the context of an update's replacement document. Consider using an aggregation pipeline with $replaceWith."}
```

Comment: Why is temp forecast history an array? Does it contain more than 1 object at any time?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: My bad: it's corrected now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Using `'10.08.2023-11.08.2023'` as a field name may lead to future query complications.  In general, using _**any**_ data as a field name is an _anti-pattern_ for MongoDB documents.